# Graphql gql with variables and Query component (deprecated)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am trying to get use graphql with query component .

```
const LOAD_PRODUCTS = gql`
  query {
    category(input :{title : "${category}"}){ 
      name
      products {
        id
        name
        brand
        inStock
        gallery
        prices{
          currency {
            label
            symbol
          }
          amount
        }
        attributes{
          id
          name 
          type 
          items {
            id
            displayValue
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

and later i am using the query compnent to fetch the data

```
 <Query query={LOAD_PRODUCTS} variables={{category : "all" }}></Query>
```

but react is give error that category is not defined in the gql
what to do ....

I tried all the solutions on the internet and failed.
I did not want to use the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the mapping of your query variables. Also your syntax is assuming string substitution rather than query variables.

Try:

```
const LOAD_PRODUCTS = gql`
  query myQuery ( $category: String! ) {
    category(input: { title: $category }){ 
      name
      products {
        …
      }
    }
  }
```